# Can kubernetes provide a pod with an emptyDir volume from the host backed by a specific filesystem different than the host's?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, devops, persistent-volumes

I know this is a bit weird, but I'm building an application that makes small local changes to ephemeral file/folder systems and needs to sync them with a store of record. I am using NFS right now, but it is slow, not super scalable, and expensive. Instead, I'd love to take advantage of `btrfs` or `zfs` snapshotting for efficient syncing of snapshots of a small local filesystem, and push the snapshots into cloud storage.

I am running this application in Kubernetes (in GKE), which uses GCP VMs with `ext4` formatted root partitions. This means that when I mount an `emptyDir` volume into my pods, the folder is on an `ext4` filesystem I believe.

Is there an easy way to get an ephemeral volume mounted with a different filesystem that supports these fancy snapshotting operations?

Comment: you are right in case of GCP one that will be `ext4` i believe same however i am not sure this might can help or not. https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator-Guide/Gluster-On-ZFS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Nor does GKE offer that kind of low level control anyway but the rest of this answer presumes you've managed to create a local mount of some kind. The easiest answer is a hostPath mount, however that requires you manually account for multiple similar pods on the same host so they don't collide. A new option is an ephemeral CSI volume combined with a CSI plugin that basically reimplements emptyDir. https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-host-path gets most of the way there but would 1) require more work for this use case and 2) is *explicitly* not supported for production use. Failing either of those, you can move the whole kubelet data directory onto another mount, though that might not accomplish what you are looking for.